# How to create custom dropdown attribute for customer in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

I want to create a custom dropdown attribute for magento customer account.

For this I have used $installer script but it is not working for me. My script as below :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "track_device",  array(
    "label"    => "Customer Device",
    'input' => 'select',
    'type'  => 'int',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'option' => array('values' => array('Web', 'App')) 

));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "track_device");

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Is anything missing or wrong in this script?

Is any another method to create custom dropdown attribute in customer account in magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId     = (int)$installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'track_device', array(
    'type'               => 'int',
    'label'              => 'Customer Device',
    'input'              => 'select',
    'forms'              => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
    'source'             => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'required'           => false,
    'visible'            => 1,
    'user_defined'       => true, /* To display in frontend */
    'position'           => 110,
    'option'             => array('values' => array('Web', 'App'))
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'track_device', 100);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'track_device');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();


?>
```

Comment: Hello @Abdul, this is not working for me, I have not found `Customer Device` dropdown field in customer account information tab in magento admin panel after apply this script.

Comment: Pls refresh magento cache to admin side system -> Cache Management and refresh all caches and check again in customer acoount

Comment: I have already remove cache, reindex data, logout from admin panel and login again but it is not showing me any custom field in customer account.

Comment: Pls create test.php file at magento root folder and add bellow code in file

Comment: updated ans so please add code in test.php file and run this file in browser after check in customer account

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

//$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'note', array(
    'type'      => 'text',
    'label'     => 'Note',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'input'     => 'textarea',
    'position'  => 32,
    'required'  => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'note',
    '100'
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'note');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit')); 
$oAttribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();
```