# How to add custom dropdown on customer address checkout in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, module, checkout, magento-2.1.3, custom-attributes

How can we add ***custom dropdown field on the checkout page in customer address***. Also, it *should be reflected in the backend and in Customer my account* section.

For example:-

Customer primary business

Dropdown options like

- Technician
- Business
- End user

I have created for Magento-1.9 using [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100582/how-to-create-custom-dropdown-attribute-for-customer-in-magento) But not having much information for Magento 2.1.x

Comment: please refer this discussion https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100582/how-to-create-custom-dropdown-attribute-for-customer-in-magento

Comment: @swathi_sri Thanks. But its solved now.